# Given a bijection in G ={1,2,3} and K={h,g,f} that would show that the symmetric groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am a bit lost with this question: Give a bijection in $G={1,2,3}$ and $K={h,g,f}$, and the corresponding bijection of elements in $S_G$ and $S_K$, that would show that they are isomorphic.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151075/120540) is one of my favorite answers, and may give you some ideas.

Comment: You don't say anything about any progress you've made, so I guess you're stuck on the first step, i.e., you haven't been able to find a bijection from $G$ to $K.$ Have I got that right? Is that the part you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a bijection $\beta: G \to K$, consider the map:

$\phi: S_G \to S_K$, which sends $\sigma \in S_G$ to $\beta\circ\sigma\circ \beta^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I applied your proposition to one specific symmetry (i.e. a rotation by 1 element) ... it does show that it renders similar symmetry (rotation by 1 element) with the elements of K it is therefore an homomorphism. I wrote that because  $\beta\circ\sigma\circ \beta^{-1}$ describes 2 compositions of bijections, the resulting homomorphism is a bijection => therefore it is an isomorphism.

Comment: using $\sigma$={a rotation of G by 1 element}={2,3,1}